# How to return multiple hit counts for multiple search strings in elasticsearch extraction query?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a many to many kind of query.

I want to combine multiple search strings in a single query and I want hit counts for each of them.
For example:

"Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"

For each of them, I want a count.

Currently, I have written OR query, but that defeats the purpose.
OR query combines everything, and hit count is accumulation of all of the search strings,
but, I want a hit count specifically for each search string.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Elasticsearch is not a relational database trying to implement RDBMS behaviour will be doom to fail eventually.

But with that said, if you just want to count the number of it for a series of  `terms`,  you should be looking into the [aggregation feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) of elasticsearch.

In the case you absolutely want to perform search queries, you could try to look into the [msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) api allowing you to send multiple queries to elasticsearch using a single call.

## Solution (aggregation)

```json
GET <index name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "fruits": [
        "Apple",
        "Orange",
        ...
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fruits",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Solution (msearch)

```json
GET <index name>/_msearch
{ }
{"query": {"terms": {"fruits": ["Apple"]}}}
{}
{"query": {"terms": {"fruits": ["Orange"]}}}
...
```